# Acer Aspire e11 es1-111m and touchpad on debian

Tags: debian, touchpad

I installed Debain on my Acer es1-111m laptop and my touchpad isn't working. When I was on Linux Mint, all was OK. What can I do to repair touchpad?

```
egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices
```

is returning :

```
"N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
```

I haven't got any desktop so i use i3 tilling window manager.

Comment: Welcome to superuser  please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1149007/edit) by adding the output of `egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices` and your desktop environment KDE , Gnome ...

Comment: Have you got any idea?

Comment: Run `synclient tapbutton1=1` as user

Comment: I did it without any effect

Comment: egrep returned "N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"